# complex object is null in Web API method using Httpclient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have Web API service deployed and and consuming in another web application. Web API method take complex object (List object) and results also complex object.

So I created local models for Input parameter and results model to match with Web API complex objects in web application. then I passed `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` for that parameter. But when I debug in Web API that parameter value showing null.

### Web application

```
 [Serializable]
    public class PreferencesInput
    {
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        public string ShortNameDescription { get; set; }
       .....
    } 

  [Serializable]
    public class PreferencesOuput
    {
       public bool Status { get; set; }
       public string Error { get; set; }
     }
     public class HomeController : Controller
     {
           public ActionResult Index()
          {
                RunAsync().Wait();
                return View();
          }

           private static async Task RunAsync()
           {
             var inputs = new List<PreferencesInput>();
             var input = new PreferencesInput
              {
                   ShortName = "REGION",
                   ShortNameDescription = "Geographical regions",
                   OptedInFlag = true
              };
              inputs.Add(input);
              ....
              ...
              using (var client = new HttpClient())
              {
                  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8585/");
                  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                try
                {
                     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("preferences/updatepreferences/?id='3016523'
                      &optInInterestAreas=" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inputs) + 
                      "&solicitationFlag=false").ConfigureAwait(false);;

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string results = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PreferencesOuput>>(results);
                    }
```

### web API

```
  [Route("preferences/updatepreferences")]
    [HttpGet]
    public PreferencesOuput UpdatePreferences(string id, IEnumerable<PreferencesInput> optInInterestAreas, bool solicitationFlag)
    {
       .....
    }
```

Only difference is Web application Input model has less parameters than the Web API model.

What I am doing wrong here?

`IEnumerable<PreferencesInput> optInInterestAreas` is null

### update

I can see serialization date like below before sending to Web API call, In Web API method it is showing null, rest of the parameters are showing correct.

```
    [{"ShortName":"REGION","ShortNameDescription":"Geographical regions","ShortSubName":null,"Description":null,"OptedInFlag":true},
{"ShortName":"REGION","ShortNameDescription":"Asia Pacific","ShortSubName":"ASIA_PACIFIC","Description":null,"OptedInFlag":true},
{"ShortName":"REGION","ShortNameDescription":"Canada","ShortSubName":"CANADA","Description":null,"OptedInFlag":true}]
```

Comment: Just wondering if you have verified your query string is correct

Comment: Your query string is not valid. Could you try with HttpPost?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to specify the route with parameters. Something like:

```
[Route("preferences/updatepreferences/{id}/{optInInterestAreas}/{solicitationFlag:bool}")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `optInInterestAreas` parameter is null because in Web API, the [parameter binding rules](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) specify that anything other than a "simple" parameter type (string, int, etc) is assumed to be passed in the body, not the route or query string as you're doing. You *could* get this to work by using the `[FromUri]` attribute on that parameter or by defining a custom type converter, but I would highly recommend changing your API as it does not follow generally accepted best practices.

By convention, `GET` is assumed to be side-effect-free, but I'm guessing something called UpdatePreferences almost certainly changes data. I would consider using a different verb and passing the updated preferences in the body. `POST` is better, but if you want it to be truly RESTful, you should **ensure that the URI uniquely identifies the resource and use `PUT`**.

I would start by changing your input model to something like this:

```
public class PreferencesInput
{
    public IList<InterestArea> InterestAreas { get; set; }
    public bool SolicitationFlag { get; set; }
}

public class InterestArea
{
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string ShortNameDescription { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then define your API action like this:

```
[Route("preferences/{id}")]
[HttpPut]
public PreferencesOuput UpdatePreferences(string id, PreferencesInput preferences)
{
    ...
}
```

As you can see, the URI now uniquely identifies the thing, and the verb specifies what you want to "do"; in this case, completely replace whatever is at that URI (if anything) with the thing you are passing.

---

**Side-note:**

On the MVC side, calling `Wait()` in your Index action is blocking a thread while waiting for your async method to complete. That's a serious invitation for deadlocks. Async only works properly if you go "all the way" with it. In this case it's incredibly easy - just change the Index action to:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    await RunAsync();
    return View();
}
```